# get previous row where column equals same value ms access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Is it possible to get the previous row where a specific column equals a specific value.

Example of what I have tried.

```
        //Prev ID
        int numval = Convert.ToInt32(pointid.Text);
        int id = numval;
        id--;
        //textBox1.Text = id.ToString();
        //int prevval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        //Point Type ID
        int catid = Convert.ToInt32(catId.Text);

        cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Points WHERE points_type_id = @catid and point_id = @prevval";
        cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prevval", id);
        cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", catid);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            pointlbl.Text = reader["point"].ToString();
            //To be used for next previous buttons to only get results from the same catid
            //int type = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("point_id"));
            catId.Text = reader["points_type_id"].ToString();
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader["Description"].ToString();
        }

        conGet.Close();
```

So I have little dot points that when they are clicked it displays the data for that point id match in the id column. Then I have previous and next buttons where I want to display the previous or next row if the point_type_id matches the same categoryid.

This does not work.

Here is and example of what the table looks like.

```
ID | Point | point_type_id
1      A          1
2      B          1
3      C          2
4      D          2
5      E          1
```

So say I start out on the fifth row ID = 5 which has point_type_id = 1, I want to get the previous row with point_type_id = 1 which would be the third row ID = 3

Comment: Remove the semi colon which you mentioned inside of the query. You can't pass the query with semi colon.

Comment: Good catch but that isn't the problem, and I do not believe top(1) is for previous row but the top n of rows. Still get the same error without the colon.

Comment: Also be aware of using Top clause in sql query. Top clause won't execute with using Top(). It will take this as function. So try by removing () in top clause

Comment: I tried cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT top1 FROM Points WHERE points_type_id = @catid"; and get indexoutofrange

Comment: Check my answer in the following.

Comment: How the previous row would be third row ?. What you said is making us so confuse. 'So say I start out on the fifth row ID = 5 which has point_type_id = 1, I want to get the previous row with point_type_id = 1 which would be the third row ID = 3'

Comment: Maybe "row" was bad choice of wording, but figured it would make sense sorry. I want the previous ID, which has the same points_type_id... Obviously the previous row wouldn't be three but the row I would be after would be the third.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57248/discussion-between-gkrishy-and-bowenac).

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought...

```
        cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Points WHERE point_id < @curval and points_type_id = @catid";
        cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curval", numval);
        cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", catid);
```